# Is there a possibility to perform a right-click on an element with the casper framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using the CasperJS framework to do some click testing on a DOM tree. Apparently CasperJS only supports left-clicking and some other mouse events but no right click on an element:

http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/mouse.html#click

Unfortunately we are using right-click events to open a context menu and I want to simulate that with casper. So any workaround would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think currently, there's no way you can achieve it. `Casperjs` support many mouse events such as `click`, `double click`, `mouse up`, `mouse down` for drag and drop feature... but only applicable for left click.

However if you're able to modify the `casperjs` core framework based on this [solution](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/5b25c6feea66782999c6949b7595d1bbb832c89d) from this [question](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10712) for `phantomjs` (`casperjs` built on top of `phantomjs`) then take a shot :).

Besides that, you can also seek for `casperjs` support from [Github repo](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues) or [Codersplan](http://www.codersclan.net/?repo_id=32)